# EPPlus formula error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to put formula in a cell using EPPlus.

In my workbook I have 2 sheets

- Cover
- Comments

"Comments" sheet gets filled using database at runtime, in column D values is like "P" or "C".

In "Cover" sheet I want to get the total number of "P" in a cell from Comments Sheet. Formula I am using is  -

```
=COUNTIF(Comments!D:D,"P")
```

In program i am added formula to cell as

```
cellRange.Formula = string.Format("COUNTIF(Comments!{D}:D," +@"""P)""");
```

But during debug i am getting exception - "Input string was not in a correct format."

where I am getting wrong?

Comment: I can only see one argument to the `Format` method. Where are the rest?

Comment: I tried this one  var cellRange = ws.Cells[18, 6];      ExcelColumn column = workbook.Worksheets[1].Column(4);  
    cellRange.Formula = string.Format("COUNTIF(Comments!{0}:{1}," + @"""P)""", column, column);   getting error - "object refrence not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: corrected to 

cellRange.Formula = string.Format("COUNTIF(Comments!{0}:{1},\"P\")", column, column);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `{}`, perhaps?

Assuming that the formula works in excel and gives you the required count, try this

cellRange.Formula = "COUNTIF(Comments!D:D,\"P\")";